# How to replace one column values with another column values

Tags: python, pandas, replace, group-by

Actually I want to replace the prefix with the mean here.
How can i acheive it.
When replacing it it is replacing with NaN but not with the mean values.

**This is my code:**

[image: My code]

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to replace the teacher_prefix with their corresponding mean values

Comment: so both columns become the mean values?

Comment: Yes  i need to replace

Comment: Try my updated solution.

Comment: glad to help. do vote the solutions if they helped so it encourages me to help you in the future as well :)

Comment: Sure brother!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second column is a multi-index column, you are basically trying to set a single column as a dataframe. You will have to refer to the exact column name to do that replacement.

```
z['ID']=z['teacher_number_of_previously_posted_projects']['mean']
```